# Azure Translate Text

Tags: azure

Not able to use Azure cognitive services.

Tried running sample code provided from azure itself https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Java, but no luck:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "404",
        "message": "Resource not found"
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have updated the code with both my subscription key and domain name.

No luck after following all azure provided document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-language-detection

Comment: Have you gone through the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-not-found-errors)?

Comment: gone through documents, but looks like documentation mismatch between existing azure service screens w.r.t document